# Is jQuery on Node and Windows Azure Hosting possible?

Tags: node.js, deployment, azure

I'm struggling to deploy a node app to Azure really hard. Because I use jQuery and it's dependant on Contextify (which seems to have a problem with windows) I'm just going in circles.

Has anyone managed to successfully deploy a node app to Azure which uses jQuery, and if so, how!?!?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are trying to deploy your sollution on an Azure Web Role. You can run into problems using the Web Role. Try instead deploying it to a Worker Role.

For an example of how to do this see: http://coderead.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/windows-azure-and-node-js/

Comment: This article is old and he is using jQuery on the client not server, this scenario would work now.